# How do you change the clock icon color next to recent queries android

Tags: java, android, icons, material-design

[image: recent icon can be seen at the far left]

How do I change the color of the white clock next to the suggestions? In the screenshot the recent clocks are seen at the far left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is on parameter called `android:tint` for `Imageview`.

define your `ImageView` something like this

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/hist_image"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:tint="#colorcode"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/search_last" />
```

you can set color programmatically too.

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),  
                             android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

For more information on that refer [this Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(android.graphics.ColorFilter)). I hope this will help.

Happy Coding.

Comment: What XML file would I put that ImageView in? And which Java file would I use for imageView.setColorFilter? Thanks

Comment: xml which you are using as list item.